# Problem in Automatic Sliding Background Images - Html and Css

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I am trying to make background images slideshow which automatically floats images to left after some time, My slideshow has 6 images, but only 1st image slides to left and then nothing happens, Maybe, It looks-like all other images are covered by the 1st image?

My code Gist (only 50 lines)
: https://gist.github.com/Reevan799/da93136825c318e0d91b73887ec408ed

I am trying to do it from this youtube tutorial
: https://youtu.be/Wyfgv7LLno4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the main problem is that you set you `.slider figure { width: 500%; }`, then `.slider figure div { width: 100%; }`.
Supose that your viewport is 1366px width, then 500% is 6830px, your inner divs with width 100% are getting the full width of 6830px not only 1366px.

A quick fix would be set `.slider figure div { width: 100vw; }`using viewport width instead `%`.

Also your css is a little messed up, things like, the classes order, you are using  tags and styling background, in this case a nice approach is to set the image as background-image and use then the propertie background-cover start to work and gets nice.

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/07dgsq12/

PS: Sorry about my english